# MySQL: Query not always returning lowest most recent price across multiple stores

Tags: mysql, function, min

The below SQL is returning the lowest most recent price for each product if there is only price information for a single store, if there is price information for more then one store the most recent lowest price isn't always returned!?

**Wanted Outcome**

Return the lowest price for a product from the most recent price information across all stores so if there were 6 stores it would display the lowest price from the most recent price record for each of the 6 stores.

If the most recent price is the same across all store price records and the updated date is also the same then the records can be ordered by store to select the price for the product in question.

`{product id}` is a value passed in depending what product is being displayed.

**SQL**

```
SELECT `vsp`.`prod_id`
, `vsp`.`price`
, `vsp`.`store`
, `vsp`.`updated`
FROM `price` `vsp`
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM `price` `vsp2`
    WHERE `vsp2`.`prod_id` = `vsp`.`prod_id`
    AND `vsp`.`prod_id` = {product id}
    AND (`vsp2`.`updated` > `vsp`.`updated` OR (`vsp2`.`updated` = `vsp`.`updated` AND `vsp2`.`price` < `vsp`.`price`))
) AND `vsp`.`prod_id` = {product id}
```

**price**

```
prod_id     | price     | store | updated
--------------------------------------------------------
product 1   | 1.99      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 2   | 1.49      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:10:00
product 2   | 1.19      | 2     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 3   | 12.49     | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 3   | 12.49     | 2     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 4   | 9.89      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 5   | 10.00     | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:10:00
product 5   | 9.99      | 2     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 5   | 10.49     | 3     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
```

**Expected Output**

```
product 1   | 1.99      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 2   | 1.49      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:10:00
product 3   | 12.49     | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 4   | 9.89      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 5   | 9.99      | 2     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
```

**Current Output**

```
product 1   | 1.99      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 2   | 1.49      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:10:00
product 3   | 12.49     | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 4   | 9.89      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 5   | 10.00     | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:10:00
```

**Update #1**

The select itself looks to be working great and only returning one price when I add the `prodId` constraint onto the query, the issue now is if I add the select statement to a function it gives the below error even though I only see one value returned when I run the select on it's own.

```
Result consisted of more than one row
```

**SQL Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_GET_SET_LOWEST_PRICE (`prodId` VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS DOUBLE
BEGIN
    DECLARE `latestPrice` DOUBLE(7,2) DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT p3.price
    INTO `latestPrice`
    FROM price p3
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT p1.prod_id, MIN(p1.price) AS minPrice
        FROM price p1
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT prod_id, MIN(updated) AS minUpdated
            FROM price
            GROUP BY prod_id
        ) p2
        ON p1.prod_id = p2.prod_id AND p1.updated = p2.minUpdated
        GROUP BY p1.prod_id
    ) t
    ON p3.prod_id = t.prod_id AND p3.price = t.minPrice
    WHERE p3.prod_id = prodId;

    RETURN `latestPrice`;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I think it might help us if you tell us, in plain English, what the logic is for deciding which `product` record to retain, in the case where a `product` has more than one record in the `price` table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks for the feedback, I've added the `wanted outcome` snippet to the question to try clear up what I'm trying to do.

Comment: How are you deciding to retain store 1 for `product 3` and not store 2?  How do handle this tie scenario?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I never spotted that, but yes that is another case that isn't accounted for, I would say I could just order by store in that situation but not sure how that might affect the overall outcome I'm trying to come to.

Comment: Feel free to upvote me for the 45 minutes I spent answering your question.

Comment: product 5   | 10.00     | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:10:00 -- according what you said, this should be the correct result, as it is the last update timestamp for product5

Comment: Can you tell me why the expected result for product 5 is this: product 5   | 9.99      | 2     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00

Answer (score 2):

I would gravitate towards using a series of inner joins to get your result set, rather than a complicated subquery in the `WHERE` clause, which is hard to read.

```
SELECT p3.prod_id, p3.price, p3.store, p3.updated
FROM price p3
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT p1.prod_id, MIN(p1.price) AS minPrice
    FROM price p1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT prod_id, MIN(updated) AS minUpdated
        FROM price
        GROUP BY prod_id
    ) p2
    ON p1.prod_id = p2.prod_id AND p1.updated = p2.minUpdated
    GROUP BY p1.prod_id
) t
ON p3.prod_id = t.prod_id AND p3.price = t.minPrice
```

Follow the link below for a running demo:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b894f/1)

**Update:**

If you want to use this query like a function, then you will have to create a stored procedure.  The reason for this is that a function must return only one value.  Even if you contrive a query which *should* only return a single value, MySQL will still complain.

Try something along the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FN_GET_SET_LOWEST_PRICE(prodId VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    SELECT p3.price
    FROM price p3
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT p1.prod_id, MIN(p1.price) AS minPrice
        FROM price p1
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT prod_id, MIN(updated) AS minUpdated
            FROM price
            GROUP BY prod_id
        ) p2
        ON p1.prod_id = p2.prod_id AND p1.updated = p2.minUpdated
        GROUP BY p1.prod_id
    ) t
    ON p3.prod_id = t.prod_id AND p3.price = t.minPrice
    WHERE p3.prod_id = prodId;
END
```

Comment: Looks to be running correctly with some quick testing. One last question if I drop that query into a function that returns a double it gives out saying you cant return a resultset, any ideas?

Comment: Isn't this error self-explanatory?  The query is returning multiple records, each of which contains values from multiple columns.  If you want to use this in a function I believe you will have to configure it to return a single value.  This could be done using a `WHERE` clause, along with a `SELECT` of a single column value.

Comment: I've added a constraint on `p3.prod_id` using a `ẀHERE` clause and it select returns a single price which is correct but in the function it gives out about single row being returned, I've updated the original question with the details, appreciate your help so far!

Comment: I mispoke yesterday.  A MySQL function apparently can not return _any_ result set from a query, because it is impossible to be certain that it really will return a single value.  You must use a stored procedure instead.

Comment: Just noticed an issue with the SQL [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cd56/2), this should just pick the first record in the instance of the same price and updated date, this could be why the function gives out about more then one row being returned per product.

Comment: No this should not matter because you added a `WHERE` clause which should restrict to one record.  Please try using a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you actually want:

```
1 - find the last updated
2 - find the cheapest if last updated is multiple
```

And here is the SQL:

```
SELECT price.*
FROM price, (
    SELECT price.prod_id, last_price.max_updated, min(price.price) min_price
    FROM price, (
        SELECT prod_id,max(updated) max_updated 
        FROM price
        GROUP BY 1
    ) as last_price
    WHERE price.prod_id = last_price.prod_id
    AND   price.updated = last_price.max_updated
    GROUP BY 1,2
) as lowest_price
WHERE price.prod_id = lowest_price.prod_id
AND   price.updated = lowest_price.max_updated
AND   price.price   = lowest_price.min_price
```